# Permission denied error in wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: wordpress, permission-denied

I once moved my wordpress directory one level up on my server (its now in the root). Everything seems to work fine for a while but niow i'am starting to have troubles with uploading images.

When i try to include an image by uploading it from my computer wordpress throws an "Permission denied" error:

```
copy(/home/bram/domains/dutchmountaineer.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Costa-Rican-Frog.jpg)

[function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
/home/bram/domains/dutchmountaineer.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 348
    618
```

I tried setting the uploads and includes folder to 777 which had no effect. I have set them back to 755.

Any help please!

Jorrit

EDIT:

I tried changing the full path (in media settings) but it was of now help. I think it since i moved the wp installation from /wp/ to the root of my server

Answer (score 1):

Check who owns the directory. It may be possible that you need to add www-data to the group. Weird, yes, but I sometimes encounter scenarios where even files and directories with 777 are denying me access if I don't add my user to the owner group.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are getting error near this code

```
    // Copy the temporary file into its destination
$new_file = $uploads['path'] . "/$filename";
copy( $tmp_file, $new_file );
unlink($tmp_file);
```

check your settings under settings->Media tab in admin panel and check you have the appropriate permissions for the folder, you can change the upload path as well. Let me know if problem still persists.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You have to allow uploads directory 777 rights and check your folder user and ftp user are same or not.

Comment: "You have to allow uploads directory 777..." Absolutely wrong. 777 permissions are never necessary except in temporary cases where they are set back to 755 or tighter. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions